# Cookieless static files

Tags: static

I'm trying to setup a cookieless domain in accordance with [Google's instructions](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/speed/page-speed/docs/request.html#ServeFromCookielessDomain) for best serving static files. I'd like to do this on a subdomain instead of a completely separate domain. Does this serve the purpose? Can I have cookies on my main domain, but have a cookieless subdomain of it that serves static files? Does it matter if the cookieless subdomain is on the same IP address or not (i.e. served from the same location vs. a CDN)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of cookieless domain for static files is to prevent of sending and receiving the cookies of your site when you are getting the static files. You need to check if you get this behavior with your solution. You can use tools like httpwatch to see it.

EDIT: I found a link very useful about it.
http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/

Comment: http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/ was very helpful... great article. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add following header and hide Set-Cookies by fastcgi.

```
server{

     listen       80;
     server_name  yourdomain.com;

     location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|svg|woff|ttf|eot)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires    30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        fastcgi_hide_header Set-Cookie;
     }
}
```